# How can I port apps from OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion to OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: upgrade, macos

In Mountain Lion, many of the day-to-day apps like Preview, TextEdit have been upgraded with some very useful features. (For instance, you can now insert a page into a PDF document using your scanner in Preview - see [here](http://lifehacker.com/5928950/top-10-secret-features-of-os-x-mountain-lion), and pinch the trackpad for zooming in on to a document - see [here](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html)). However, as far as I understand, these apps are free, and features like these are features of the app themselves, not the OS.

Is there anyway in which I can replace/upgrade individual apps in Lion, without having to install it as a whole (preferably as a [dual-boot config](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58107/is-it-possible-to-dual-boot-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-and-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion)!) ?

Comment: "These apps" - Preview, for example - aren't really free. They are shipped with Mac OS X. I think it's reasonable to consider them a fairly integral part of the OS, which you are both paying for, and are tied to that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Apple does not distribute these apps individually.
Even if you copy them from one Mountain Lion system to a Lion machine, they are very likely to *not* work as they are relying on system level framework (or functions in these frameworks) that won't be available in OS X before ML